# GCC inline assembly MOD operation

Tags: assembly, inline, modulo

Can anybody provide equivalent code to below code that works within a function to compute z = x MOD y in GCC?
where x, y are double type.

assembly code:

```
        ; Compute z = x mod y
        fld y
        fld x
    L:  fprem1
        fstsw x
        test ah, 100b
        jnz L
        fstp z
```

Thanks.  I came up with this but I got "error: expected ‘:’ or ‘)’ before ‘L’
" error

```
    double mod(double x, double y)
    {
      double rslt;
      __asm__ ( "fldl %2;"
      "fldl %1;"
      "pushl %eax;"
    L: "fprem1;"
      "fstsw %1;"
      "test $4, %ah;" // test
      "jnz L;"
      "popl %eax;"
      "fstpl %0;" : "=m" (rslt) : "m"(x), "m"(y)
      );
      return rslt;      
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you have what you need already. Are you having trouble with the inline assembly syntax, or what?

Comment: Exactly. This code is from "The Art of Assembly Language" book but I'm not familiar with this syntax neither I'm versed in GCC inline asm.

Comment: Everything you need is available here: https://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html If you have a more specific question than just "how do I use GCC inline assembly," please feel free to ask!

Comment: You need to put the label into the string.  That said, you should not use raw label names from inline assembly.  Instead, use `%=` to form a label name as specified in the manual.

Comment: Still get error "invalid 'asm': operand number missing after %-letter" if I keep the test instruction.

Comment: %eax needs to be %%eax and %ah needs to be %%ah

Comment: Instead of pushing and popping eax, you should add eax to the clobber list. To do this, add ` : “eax” ` right before the closing parenthesis of the asm statement.

Comment: Pretty sure you want `fstsw ax`, not `x`.  You're testing AH, not memory, after that.  Also, use an output constraint to leave the result in `st0` instead of storing to memory where the compiler will have to reload it.  (Although it will anyway if you're compiling normal code that uses SSE2 for FP math, not legacy x87)

Comment: Yes, I did all necessary corrections and code works now. I want it to be compatible with legacy x87 since I might use Pentium II based hardware but why should I leave the result in st0 since the function must return the result?

Comment: @OmarA It's best to let the compiler care about moving the result into the right place than to move it there yourself at the end.  This often leads to more efficient code.

Comment: How the compiler will know that I want to return whatever in st0? Is it implicit in this case?